# How to compare two dimensional list that is not in another two dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have two list that are two dimensional. I would like to compare df0 that is not in df1. This is the code i have below but it only giving me the matching value.

For Example:

```
df0=[[2, 4, 7, 13, 14],
     [3, 5, 8, 13, 14],
     [6, 9, 10, 13, 14]]

df1=[[4, 7, 9, 12],
     [12, 15, 17, 18, 19],
     [13, 22, 23, 24, 30],
     [2, 5, 7, 8, 9],
     [6, 7, 12, 14, 15]]

df3= list(enumerate([[list(set(x) & set(y))
                      for x in df0
                      if x not in df1]
                     for y in df1]))
```

I would like my results to be:

```
[[[9, 12], [], [22,23,24,30], [5,8,9], [6,12,15]],
 [[], [], [22,23,24,30], [2,7,9], [6,7,12,15]],
 [[], [], [22,23,24,30], [], [7,12,15]]]
```

Comment: Where does [122,23,24,30] comes from?

Comment: Are results you posted connected to problem you've described?

Comment: It comes from df1

Comment: `df1` doesn't contain a `122`, Chriss88.

Comment: @Chris88, it's unclear which algorithm can generate such as results from given data, but definitely not comparison.

Comment: I think he means a `diff` or a set subtraction.  Maybe the set-union his code shows.  Please clarify, Chriss88!

Comment: What's the question? Is your solution deficient? How? Have you ruled anything out? Which part do you suspect?

Comment: Basically if df0 match df1 i would like it to return only the ones that is not in the matching list

Comment: Looks like OP is looking for the `set.difference`, `[[list(set(x).difference(y)) for x in df1] for y in df0]` I suspect, though the expected result is partially correct

Comment: I'm currently wondering how the empty list after `[9,12]` can happen.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Alfe, does it the only logical gap you've found? :D

Comment: Rewrite/unwind your (nested?) comprehension to *regular* for loops so you can inspect intermediate results/ What did you find?

Comment: @OlvinRoght No, but the need to offer constructive criticism forces me to pick a single point and start clarifying only that first.  Maybe the clarification of that solves all the other mysteries as well.  With the given input I don't see how an empty set (or list) can appear in the output at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes something like that . It worked but is there a way return the values not in by only the matching values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired result can be achieved by applying this algorithm:

```
[ [ list(sorted(set(x) - set(y)))
    if set(y) & set(x)
    else []
    for x in df1 ]
  for y in df0 ]
```

But if this makes any sense, that's up to you :)

Comment: Well, also not quite, as I see now.  The last row isn't the same.  But maybe as a proposal it helps figuring out what OP means.

Comment: this woks thank you so much. also how do you put enumerate in your list comprehension you put in the comment.